# Is it possible to determine the signal received by last running application?

Tags: linux, bash, signals

From a shell, say Bash, is it possible to retrieve the signal number received by the application that most recently finished, if any, in a way that is similar to checking the return code of a process by printing `$?`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux signals logger](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/linux-signals-logger)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a process is killed, the signal that killed it is encoded in the exit status retrieved by the parent (or child subreaper or `init` for orphans).

In `bash`, `$?` is 128+signum.

That's what most Bourne-like shells do, ksh93 uses 256+signum, yash 384+signum.

`$?` being `129` in `bash` either means the process was killed by signal 1 (SIGHUP) or that it did a `exit(129)`. If it did a `exit(129)` however, most likely that was to report a death by SIGHUP of some process.

To get the signal name from the value of `$?`, run:

```
kill -l "$?"
```

That works in all Bourne-like shells whether they use 128/256/384 + signum.

See details at [Default exit code when process is terminated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99112)